# Reading from a text file error: strange '\x01' '\0' '\0' '0' sequences

Tags: c, file, text, stream, fread

I am reading a plain text from a file - by lines, with a following function:

```
int readline(FILE *in, char * buf) {
char c;
buf[0]='\0';
for (int i=0; i<BUFSIZ-1; i++) {
    fread(&c,1,1,in);
    if (ferror(in)) return 1; 
    if (feof(in)) break;
    buf[i]=c; 
    if (c=='\n') break;
    }
    if (buf[BUFSIZ-1]!='\0') return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It reads correctly 28816 characters, and then the trouble starts.
Instead of reading the next four characters:

```
' ' 'f' 'o' 'r'
```

it reads the weird thing:

```
'\x01' '\0' '\0' '\0'
```

After that, it reads everything correctly until 33080 character.
Instead of reading next 12 characters correctly, it reads three sequences:

```
'\x01' '\0' '\0' '\0' '\x01' '\0' '\0' '\0' '\x01' '\0' '\0' '\0'
```

Then, it reads everything correctly again, until certain point.

There weren't neither (ferror(in)) nor (feof(in)) condition true when this problem occurs.

Do you have any ideas about the cause of this problem?

Comment: You do realize that you could replace most of your loop with just: `fgets(buf, bufsize, in);`, right?

Comment: Does this happen with different text files, or only one particular one? And, just to clarify, it puts the 4 characters in the buffer instead of the original chars, right? It doesn't insert them in between? How do you test this; immediately after this function ends, or does the program do other things before you have a chance to test?

Comment: @MrLister It happens with different text files. It puts 4 characters instead of original chars. I have tested using probably the most reliable way: after `buf[i]=c`, I put `if (c=='\x01') {c='\x01';}` and put a brakepoint for `c='\x01'` line. That way, I could get to the place where an error occurs, and using "step over instruction" debug feature, check what happens next.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Unfortunately, this doesn't solve an issue (I replaced the whole cycle by `fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, in);`

Comment: try adding that test straight after the fread as well and adding breakpoint there, only seen this sort of thing with stack crash on emebedded hardware.

Comment: Not sure what to ask now. I presume that BUFSIZE is large enough to hold the largest line in the file? What happens if you copy the file to another disk first? Just grasping at straws.

Comment: @MrLister BUFSIZE is large enough, because there is no lines that are longer than BUFSIZE and it stops reading as soon as it gets newline character. Moreover, that thing happens when the buffer is far from overfilling. Tried to make a file copy to make sure that the file isn't damaged, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Dampsquid I have already done that, there were not any stack crashes; and it have read nearly 30k characters successfully before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like random data - it is the byte sequence for an integer value of 1 (assuming x86 or similar CPU).

I would expect one of two situations:

1) you're writing off the end of the buffer, and something else is using the same memory

2) somewhere else in your program, you're writing off the end of another array into the memory used by the buffer.

From the comments, I see you've debugged it, seemingly ruling out both options.  I wonder whether optimisation was disabled when you were debugging?  I've had tricky experiences debugging an optimised binary in the past.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I am going try it.